# Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-service-worker

I am using Angular4 and currently started exploring Services of Angular4. I have done everything right in my dataServices class but still i am getting this error in argument of`observer.next(1);`\

Please tell me where i am wrong.

**Error:**

```
Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'
```

**data.service.ts:**

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
>
>
> @Injectable()
>
> export class DataService{
>     data: Observable<Array<number>>;
>
> constructor(){
>
> }
> getData(){
>     this.data = new Observable(observer =>{
>         setTimeout(() =>{
>             observer.next(1);
>         }, 1000);
>
>         setTimeout(() =>{
>             observer.next(2);
>         }, 2000);
>
>         setTimeout(() =>{
>             observer.next(3);
>         }, 3000);
>
>         setTimeout(() =>{
>             observer.next('Hello');
>         }, 4000);
>
>         setTimeout(() =>{
>             observer.complete();
>         }, 5000);
>     });
>
>     return this.data;
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote this type for `data`:

```
data: Observable<Array<number>>;
```

But you're trying to pass a `number`, not an array of numbers. So you can just change the type of `data`:

```
data: Observable<number>;
```

Comment: It helped. Thanks

Comment: @AhmadHabib, glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

this.data is an Array of numbers, not a single number. Push your values to this.data instead.